How can i make an exact copy of a large table in BigQuery (in the same project)
I have a table in a BQ dataset that is very large and want to make an exact copy as a backup in the same project.
Of course I can always do:
CREATE TABLE `myproject.mydataset.my_new_table` AS 
SELECT *
FROM `myproject.mydataset.my_old_table`;

But the disadvantage of this is, it will read the whole table and incurs costs, which is pricey for very large tables.
What other options do i have?

For a backup, use a snapshot, it's less expensive! https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-intro

I have removed the (general, ISO/ANSI) SQL tag, since this is a very product specific case.

Great addition @guillaumeblaquiere it's a better solution, added it to my answer.

Cheapest is to create a snapshot table, you don't pay query costs for creating the table, and storage wise only for changes to the original table:
CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE `myproject.mydataset.my_new_table`
CLONE `myproject.mydataset.my_old_table`

See also: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-intro

Or, you can make an exact copy of a table with the query below.
The costs will be in the storage costs, but the creating is free.
CREATE TABLE myproject.mydataset.my_new_table
COPY myproject.mydataset.my_old_table;

See also:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copying_a_single_source_table
